# How to solve for unknowns of 3 collinear points?

Tags: calculus

The points $A: (3, -1, z), \;  B: (1, 2, 6)$ and $C: (x, 8, 14)$ are collinear. Find the values of $x$ and $z$. Help? I am not sure where to start.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  People will be more inclined to help if they know you have put some effort into finding the solution for yourself.

Comment: Points are said to be collinear if they are on the same line.

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/EqnsOfLines.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If the points are collinear, then the lie on the same line.

If $A,B,C$ are colliinear, then so are $A-B,0,C-B$, and in this case, there
must be some $t$ such that $(C-B) = t (A-B)$.

The second coordinate fixes $t$ from which you can work out the values of $x,z$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: this corresponds to having $||\vec{AB}\times \vec{AC}|| = 0$ which means that $\triangle ABC$ is degenerated.

Comment: That gives only one condition.